# Is there any way to control order in which classes are deployed in wildfly

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, architecture, ejb, cdi

This polling service is used as library (jar file).

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class PollingService {

@Inject
protected MessageConsumer consumer;

protected void init(@Observes @Initialized(ApplicationScoped.class) Object o) {
    final Set<String> subscribers = consumer.getSubscribers();
    //for each subscribers there's some task to execute.}}
```

Whereas subscriber is added by other application-scoped class from different project.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MessageListener {
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageListener.class);
private static final String TEST_QUEUE = "V3-shankar-test";

@Inject
private MessageConsumer consumer;

public void postConstruct(@Observes @Initialized(ApplicationScoped.class) Object o) {
    consumer.subscribe(TEST_QUEUE);
}
```

Is there any way to initialize Pollingservice class after MessageListener class add subscriber?

Comment: Why is the order relevant?

Comment: @Kukeltje because in order to perform tasks by polling service it needs subscribers.

Answer (score 1):

You may place [`@Priority`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/annotations/1.3/apidocs/javax/annotation/Priority.html) on the `o` parameter in each of your examples.  Typically its `int`-typed element value is something drawn or augmented from the [`javax.interceptor.Priority`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/interceptor/Interceptor.Priority.html) class' constants.  The [specification goes into some detail](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/3.0/cdi-spec-3.0.0-M4.html#observer_ordering) on observer method notification.

Comment: I think, but am not sure, OP is looking for something like the EJB `@DependsOn`. Which iirc is done automatically in CDI

Answer (score 0):

There are no mechanisms in CDI which would allow for the ordering of the initialization of the beans in the same scope (`@ApplicationScoped` in the example above).

CDI provides other capabilities to use though:

1. [`@Inject @Any Instance<>`](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/2.0/javax/enterprise/inject/Instance.html)
2. firing application-specific events

---

Code example with `Instance`:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class PollingService {

    @Inject
    @Any
    protected Instance<MessageListener> listeners;

    protected void init(@Observes @Initialized(ApplicationScoped.class) Object o) {
        for (MessageListener listener : listeners) {
            //for each subscribers there's some task to execute.
        }
    }

}
```

There is a possibility to introduce a priority handling here by detecting annotations on the actual `listener` class since code is handling the list explicitly.

---

Code example with application-specific events:

```
public class PollingServiceInit {
    private final PollingService service;
    ...

    public void subscribe(MessageConsumer consumer) {
        service.subscribe(consumer);
    }
}

@ApplicationScoped
public class PollingService {

    @Inject
    private Event<PollingServiceInit> event;

    protected void init(@Observes @Initialized(ApplicationScoped.class) Object o) {
        event.fire(new PollingServiceInit(this));
    }

    void subscribe(MessageListener listener) {
        //for each subscribers there's some task to execute.
    }

}

@ApplicationScoped
public class MessageListener {
    void onPollingServiceInit(@Observes final PollingServiceInit event) {
        event.subscribe(this);
    }
}
```